# Workdays function incl. holiday

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to use some code I found on this site to calculate working days and exclude holidays from working days. The two bits of code I used are below all is working as expected except for the holidays. It does not account for holidays not being working days:

I created the tblHolidays and included the field "HolidayDate". Any help is appreciated.

```
Public Function DateDiffWorkdays( _
    ByVal datDate1 As Date, _
    ByVal datDate2 As Date, _
    Optional ByVal booWorkOnHolidays As Boolean) _
    As Long

'   Calculates the count of workdays between datDate1 and datDate2.
'   2014-10-03. Cactus Data ApS, CPH

    Dim aHolidays() As Date

    Dim lngDiff     As Long
    Dim lngSign     As Long
    Dim lngHoliday  As Long

    lngSign = Sgn(DateDiff("d", datDate1, datDate2))
    If lngSign <> 0 Then
        If booWorkOnHolidays = True Then
            ' Holidays are workdays.
        Else
            ' Retrieve array with holidays between datDate1 and datDate2.
            aHolidays = GetHolidays(datDate1, datDate2)
        End If

        Do Until DateDiff("d", datDate1, datDate2) = 0
            Select Case WeekDay(datDate1)
                Case vbSaturday, vbSunday
                    ' Skip weekend.
                Case Else
                    ' Check for holidays to skip.
                    ' Ignore error when using LBound and UBound on an unassigned array.
                    On Error Resume Next
                    For lngHoliday = LBound(aHolidays) To UBound(aHolidays)
                        If Err.Number > 0 Then
                            ' No holidays between datDate1 and datDate2.
                        ElseIf DateDiff("d", datDate1, aHolidays(lngHoliday)) = 0 Then
                            ' This datDate1 hits a holiday.
                            ' Subtract one day before adding one after the loop.
                            lngDiff = lngDiff - lngSign
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next
                    On Error GoTo 0
                    lngDiff = lngDiff + lngSign
            End Select
            datDate1 = DateAdd("d", lngSign, datDate1)
        Loop
    End If

    DateDiffWorkdays = lngDiff

End Function

Public Function GetHolidays( _
    ByVal datDate1 As Date, _
    ByVal datDate2 As Date, _
    Optional ByVal booDesc As Boolean) _
    As Date()

'   Finds the count of holidays between datDate1 and datDate2.
'   The holidays are returned as an array of dates.
'   DAO objects are declared static to speed up repeated calls with identical date parameters.
'   2014-10-03. Cactus Data ApS, CPH

    ' The table that holds the holidays.
    Const cstrTable             As String = "ListHolidays_tbl"
    ' The field of the table that holds the dates of the holidays.
    Const cstrField             As String = "HolidayDate"
    ' Constants for the arrays.
    Const clngDimRecordCount    As Long = 2
    Const clngDimFieldOne       As Long = 0

    Static dbs              As DAO.Database
    Static rst              As DAO.Recordset

    Static datDate1Last     As Date
    Static datDate2Last     As Date

    Dim adatDays()  As Date
    Dim avarDays    As Variant

    Dim strSQL      As String
    Dim strDate1    As String
    Dim strDate2    As String
    Dim strOrder    As String
    Dim lngDays     As Long

    If DateDiff("d", datDate1, datDate1Last) <> 0 Or DateDiff("d", datDate2, datDate2Last) <> 0 Then
        ' datDate1 or datDate2 has changed since the last call.
        strDate1 = Format(datDate1, "\#yyyy\/mm\/dd\#")
        strDate2 = Format(datDate2, "\#yyyy\/mm\/dd\#")
        strOrder = Format(booDesc, "\A\s\c;\D\e\s\c")

        strSQL = "Select " & cstrField & " From " & cstrTable & " " & _
            "Where " & cstrField & " Between " & strDate1 & " And " & strDate2 & " " & _
            "Order By 1 " & strOrder

        Set dbs = CurrentDb
        Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenSnapshot)

        ' Save the current set of date parameters.
        datDate1Last = datDate1
        datDate2Last = datDate2
    End If

    lngDays = rst.RecordCount
    If lngDays = 0 Then
        ' Leave adatDays() as an unassigned array.
    Else
        ReDim adatDays(lngDays - 1)
        ' As repeated calls may happen, do a movefirst.
        rst.MoveFirst
        avarDays = rst.GetRows(lngDays)
        ' rst is now positioned at the last record.
        For lngDays = LBound(avarDays, clngDimRecordCount) To UBound(avarDays, clngDimRecordCount)
            adatDays(lngDays) = avarDays(clngDimFieldOne, lngDays)
        Next
    End If

    ' DAO objects are static.
    ' Set rst = Nothing
    ' Set dbs = Nothing

    GetHolidays = adatDays()

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems your code is not accounting for holidays correctly.
Your GetHolidays function is designed to retrieve a list of holidays between two dates, but your DateDiffWorkdays function does not effectively use this information. Here is some adjustment.

```
Do Until DateDiff("d", datDate1, datDate2 + 1) = 0
    Select Case Weekday(datDate1)
        Case vbSaturday, vbSunday
            Debug.Print datDate1, "weekend"
            ' Skip weekend.
        Case Else
            Dim isHoliday As Boolean
            isHoliday = False
            
            For lngHoliday = LBound(aHolidays) To UBound(aHolidays)
                If DateDiff("d", datDate1, aHolidays(lngHoliday)) = 0 Then
                    ' datDate1 is a holiday.
                    isHoliday = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
            
            If Not isHoliday Then
                ' This datDate1 is a working day and not a holiday.
                lngDiff = lngDiff + lngSign
            End If
    End Select
    
    datDate1 = DateAdd("d", lngSign, datDate1)
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it had some flaws. Use the much updated and faster version:

```vb
' Returns the count of full workdays between Date1 and Date2.
' The date difference can be positive, zero, or negative.
' Optionally, if WorkOnHolidays is True, holidays are regarded as workdays.
'
' Note that if one date is in a weekend and the other is not, the reverse
' count will differ by one, because the first date never is included in the count:
'
'   Mo  Tu  We  Th  Fr  Sa  Su      Su  Sa  Fr  Th  We  Tu  Mo
'    0   1   2   3   4   4   4       0   0  -1  -2  -3  -4  -5
'
'   Su  Mo  Tu  We  Th  Fr  Sa      Sa  Fr  Th  We  Tu  Mo  Su
'    0   1   2   3   4   5   5       0  -1  -2  -3  -4  -5  -5
'
'   Sa  Su  Mo  Tu  We  Th  Fr      Fr  Th  We  Tu  Mo  Su  Sa
'    0   0   1   2   3   4   5       0  -1  -2  -3  -4  -4  -4
'
'   Fr  Sa  Su  Mo  Tu  We  Th      Th  We  Tu  Mo  Su  Sa  Fr
'    0   0   0   1   2   3   4       0  -1  -2  -3  -3  -3  -4
'
' Execution time for finding working days of three years is about 4 ms.
'
' Requires table Holiday with list of holidays.
'
' 2015-12-19. Gustav Brock. Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function DateDiffWorkdays( _
    ByVal Date1 As Date, _
    ByVal Date2 As Date, _
    Optional ByVal WorkOnHolidays As Boolean) _
    As Long
    
    Dim Holidays()      As Date
    
    Dim Diff            As Long
    Dim Sign            As Long
    Dim NextHoliday     As Long
    Dim LastHoliday     As Long
    
    Sign = Sgn(DateDiff("d", Date1, Date2))
    If Sign <> 0 Then
        If WorkOnHolidays = True Then
            ' Holidays are workdays.
        Else
            ' Retrieve array with holidays between Date1 and Date2.
            Holidays = DatesHoliday(Date1, Date2, False) 'CBool(Sign < 0))
            ' Ignore error when using LBound and UBound on an unassigned array.
            On Error Resume Next
            NextHoliday = LBound(Holidays)
            LastHoliday = UBound(Holidays)
            ' If Err.Number > 0 there are no holidays between Date1 and Date2.
            If Err.Number > 0 Then
                WorkOnHolidays = True
            End If
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If
        
        ' Loop to sum up workdays.
        Do Until DateDiff("d", Date1, Date2) = 0
            Select Case Weekday(Date1)
                Case vbSaturday, vbSunday
                    ' Skip weekend.
                Case Else
                    If WorkOnHolidays = False Then
                        ' Check for holidays to skip.
                        If NextHoliday <= LastHoliday Then
                            ' First, check if NextHoliday hasn't been advanced.
                            If NextHoliday < LastHoliday Then
                                If Sgn(DateDiff("d", Date1, Holidays(NextHoliday))) = -Sign Then
                                    ' Weekend hasn't advanced NextHoliday.
                                    NextHoliday = NextHoliday + 1
                                End If
                            End If
                            ' Then, check if Date1 has reached a holiday.
                            If DateDiff("d", Date1, Holidays(NextHoliday)) = 0 Then
                                ' This Date1 hits a holiday.
                                ' Subtract one day to neutralize the one
                                ' being added at the end of the loop.
                                Diff = Diff - Sign
                                ' Adjust to the next holiday to check.
                                NextHoliday = NextHoliday + 1
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                    Diff = Diff + Sign
            End Select
            ' Advance Date1.
            Date1 = DateAdd("d", Sign, Date1)
        Loop
    End If
    
    DateDiffWorkdays = Diff

End Function
```

```vb
' Returns the holidays between Date1 and Date2.
' The holidays are returned as an array with the
' dates ordered ascending, optionally descending.
'
' The array is declared static to speed up
' repeated calls with identical date parameters.
'
' Requires table Holiday with list of holidays.
'
' 2021-12-09. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function DatesHoliday( _
    ByVal Date1 As Date, _
    ByVal Date2 As Date, _
    Optional ByVal OrderDesc As Boolean) _
    As Date()
    
    ' Constants for the arrays.
    Const DimRecordCount    As Long = 2
    Const DimFieldOne       As Long = 0
    
    Static Date1Last        As Date
    Static Date2Last        As Date
    Static OrderLast        As Boolean
    Static DayRows          As Variant
    Static Days             As Long
    
    Dim Records             As DAO.Recordset
    
    ' Cannot be declared Static.
    Dim Holidays()          As Date
    
    If DateDiff("d", Date1, Date1Last) <> 0 Or _
        DateDiff("d", Date2, Date2Last) <> 0 Or _
        OrderDesc <> OrderLast Then
        
        ' Retrieve new range of holidays.
        Set Records = RecordsHoliday(Date1, Date2, OrderDesc)
        
        ' Save the current set of date parameters.
        Date1Last = Date1
        Date2Last = Date2
        OrderLast = OrderDesc
        
        Days = Records.RecordCount
        If Days > 0 Then
            ' Get the full record count.
            Records.MoveLast
            Days = Records.RecordCount
            ' As repeated calls may happen, do a movefirst.
            Records.MoveFirst
            DayRows = Records.GetRows(Days)
            ' Records is now positioned at the last record.
        End If
        Records.Close
    End If
    
    If Days = 0 Then
        ' Leave Holidays() as an unassigned array.
        Erase Holidays
    Else
        ' Fill array to return.
        ReDim Holidays(Days - 1)
        For Days = LBound(DayRows, DimRecordCount) To UBound(DayRows, DimRecordCount)
            Holidays(Days) = DayRows(DimFieldOne, Days)
        Next
    End If
        
    Set Records = Nothing
    
    DatesHoliday = Holidays()
    
End Function
```

```vb
' Returns the holidays between Date1 and Date2 as a recordset.
' The holidays are returned as a recordset with the
' dates ordered ascending, optionally descending.
'
' Requires table Holiday with list of holidays.
'
' 2021-12-11. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function RecordsHoliday( _
    ByVal Date1 As Date, _
    ByVal Date2 As Date, _
    Optional ByVal ReverseOrder As Boolean) _
    As DAO.Recordset
        
    ' The table that holds the holidays.
    Const Table         As String = "Holiday"
    ' The field of the table that holds the dates of the holidays.
    Const Field         As String = "Date"
    
    Dim Records         As DAO.Recordset
    
    Dim FirstDate       As Date
    Dim LastDate        As Date
    Dim ReverseValues   As Boolean
    Dim Sql             As String
    Dim SqlFirstDate    As String
    Dim SqlLastDate     As String
    Dim Order           As String
    
    ReverseValues = (DateDiff("d", Date1, Date2) < 0)
    If ReverseValues Then
        FirstDate = Date2
        LastDate = Date1
    Else
        FirstDate = Date1
        LastDate = Date2
    End If
    
    SqlFirstDate = Format(FirstDate, "\#yyyy\/mm\/dd\#")
    SqlLastDate = Format(LastDate, "\#yyyy\/mm\/dd\#")
    ReverseOrder = ReverseOrder Xor ReverseValues
    Order = IIf(ReverseOrder, "Desc", "Asc")

    Sql = "Select " & Field & " From " & Table & " " & _
        "Where " & Field & " Between " & SqlFirstDate & " And " & SqlLastDate & " " & _
        "Order By 1 " & Order

    Set Records = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(Sql, dbOpenSnapshot)
        
    Set RecordsHoliday = Records
    
End Function
```

Taken from my library at **GitHub**: [VBA.Date](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Date).